# how to use i18n with date format

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, date-format, vuejs3, quasar

I'm using Quasar v2 with VueJs 3.
I'm trying to give different date formats for different languages, like "MM/DD/YYYY" for US and "DD.MM.YYYY" for DE.
This is what I have so far:

```
<template>
    <p> {{ $d(date, 'long') }} <p> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'PageIndex',
    setup() {
    const date = new Date(2021, 5, 10, 18)
    return {date}
  }
})
</script>
```

And the i18n.ts file:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'US',
    messages,
    datetimeFormats: {
        'US': {
            short: {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: 'numeric',
                day: 'numeric'
            },
            long: {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: '2-digit',
                day: '2-digit',
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                second: '2-digit',
            }

          }
})
```

How do I specify now that I want a different date format for every language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each locale can have its own date-time format by specifying an object under `datetimeFormats`, whose key is the locale name, and value defines the desired date-time format (as seen in the [`vue-i18n` docs](https://vue-i18n-next.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/datetime.html)).

You have one already for `US`, and you can add another for `DE`. Coincidentally, the format you want `DD.MM.YYYY` is achieved with the same format option you have for `US`:

```js
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'US',
  messages,
  datetimeFormats: {
    US: {
      short: {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric'
      },
      long: {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit'
      }
    },
    DE: {
      short: {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric'
      },
      long: {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: '2-digit'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-i18n-date-formats?file=src/i18n.js)